# backbone: how to pass bootstrap data without server side tags

Tags: backbone.js

The normal way to bootstrap your app with backbone as described in the docs [is this](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap)

```
var Accounts = new Backbone.Collection;
Accounts.reset(<%= @accounts.to_json %>);
```

Here, we are using the server side tags `<%= ... %>`,  `<?php echo ... ?>`, etc.

But in my app I am passing very thin HTML from the server. Something like this

```
<html><head></head><body></body>
<script src="init.js"></script>
<html>
```

In this case how should I bootstrap my data for my backbone models and collections?

Backbone recommends against using `fetch`

> Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page load — all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped in to place. fetch is intended for lazily-loading models for interfaces that are not needed immediately.

But I wonder if that's the right thing to do in cases like mine?

Comment: I would read that quote as a recommendation for optimum page loading when you are already generating dynamic content. Using fetch sounds like the right thing to do in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't want to put my opinion as an answer, but I think I can say, "there is no reason, technical or otherwise, not to use fetch to load your models on page load in this use case".  8)

Comment: I agree that using `fetch()` is not any problem at all, actually, after reading the question, get opinions against the _documentation suggestion_ is exactly what @greengit is needing. The documentation suggests you to use the `reset` preloaded way, but of course documentation doesn't say anything agains using `fetch` where fix better.

Answer (score 1):

You need your JS code to be parsed by your server side platform and that it inserts the data on it.

Two approaches can be:

#### 1. Make you `init.js` to be parsed by your server side

```
<html>
  <script src="init.js.php"></script>
<html>
```

In your `initi.js.php` you can use the *interpolate tags*.

#### 2. Load the data in a separate interpretable JS file

```
<html>
  <script src="data.js.php"></script>
  <script src="init.js"></script>
<html>
```

The `data.js.php` can be some thing like this:

```
MyApp.data = <?php echo ... ?>
```

In your `init.js` you can use `MyApp.data` to `reset` your Collections.

Comment: Can you give reasoning behind going to all that trouble over just using fetch?

Comment: @lecstor, I'm not the one that doesn't want to use `fetch()` :), I thought was one of the requirements of the question. Of course there is not any problem on using `fetch()`.. maybe, with the first approach, you will save 1 request to the server.